# Design for wall-hanging knife holder

Tags: design, carving

I want to make a wall hanging knife holder that would be appropriate for two chef's knives. A very simply idea would be to use pegs. Just hang the knife on two pegs. A more elaborate idea I had would be to make sort of a form-fitting socket that the handle and guard of the knife would fit into snugly. The problem here would be that the carving would be difficult. A slotted holder is out of the cards because there is not enough headroom to lift the knife out. Also, the holder is around head level, so it needs to be pull out, not lift out. What would be an optimal, Japanese-quality solution here?

A typical chef's knife (blade is about 8 inches, haft is about 4.5 inches):

[image]

Comment: Magnets are fairly common for this purpose these days. They can be inset from the back so they're invisible from the front.

Comment: @keshlam One of the two knives is ceramic.

Comment: What if they came in from the side. 2 boards with runners inbetween angled down for the blades?

Comment: Would you please post pictures of the knives, and rough illustrations of the designs you've considered thus far?

Comment: I have posted an example of a chef's knife. The designs I have thought of so far are using two pegs and carving a recess out of a block of wood that would fit the lower part of the handle.

Answer (score 4):

First real attempt at using sketchup as I would have a hell of a time explaining this otherwise. Magnets for this type of this are everywhere but like you said you have a ceramic knife. When I found out you were only thinking about 2 knives something like this came to mind.

[image]

Blades would enter from each side. Would obviously have to have width a little greater than your longest blade. Small riser in each end will help keep the blade holstered by giving the handle something to rest on. That fulcrum could help the blade rest on top or the holster keeping the cutting edge from sitting. That would largely depend on how your knives are weighted. Also could have small recess on the bottom for air circulation.

You could take the same basic idea and instead of the blade sitting vertical you could have it laying flat while still angled down. Such a contraption would look odd I think and the one I have picture above would have a better center of gravity and is more flush to the wall.

I would have gone for a more curved model but straight lines are easier for me right now.

All that said you could take the basic idea and arrange them in an array for more knives.

---

I know you might think the peg is too simple but I thought I would include it anyway.

[image]

Again the weight center of the blade is important for that to work. Knife is free for access. If you want to hide the pegs you could still make a partial face the concealed the blade. Just need to leave the top open the help the blade get out.

Comment: That is a pretty interesting concept, but the cabinet is mounted against a wall, so there is access from only one side. One concern I have with slot designs is that the blade would be rubbing against wood, potentially dulling it, which is why I was focusing on hanging designs.

Comment: @TreowWyrhta That is why how your knives are weighted would play an important role (see recent edit). I have another idea then....

Comment: I think the peg solution is an elegant solution

Comment: The bottom peg could be inserted at a small slant  or have a small knob attached to keep the knife from sliding off.  To eliminate the concern about the balance point, a third peg could be placed near the point.

Comment: @TreowWyrhta, If you put the knife in upside down, the dull, back edge rubs against the wood as it slides in and out, instead of the sharp cutting edge. This will help protect the edge. It might be slightly awkward getting the knife in and out when holding the handle upside down, though.

Comment: I suspect too much energy is being spent trying to figure out how to prevent the edge from dulling due to the knife holder design, when you'll probably dull it more just by using it. Also I'm not a chef but it seems like you'd want to sharpen it before or after after each use and hone it right before using it anyway.